# Sort on value (top 5) in multidimensional array

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I have the following list:

```
[{'id': 610603160301469715, 'worth': 0.17},
 {'id': 242730576195354624, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 659311972990451712, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 365975655608745985, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 472141928578940958, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 651499863736844298, 'worth': 0.02},
 {'id': 270904126974590976, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 280497242714931202, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 432610292342587392, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 408785106942164992, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 400900758444310528, 'worth': 0.04},
 {'id': 602213380274651400, 'worth': 0.06},
 {'id': 622692428213780481, 'worth': 0.0}]
```

It contains items with the `id` and `worth`. Is there any way to sort by `worth`? I don't really know what keywords I need to search. So that's why I'm asking here at the moment. I did try to search, but couldn't really find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) with a [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) as the `key`:

```
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: x['worth'])
[{'id': 242730576195354624, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 659311972990451712, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 365975655608745985, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 472141928578940958, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 270904126974590976, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 280497242714931202, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 432610292342587392, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 408785106942164992, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 622692428213780481, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 651499863736844298, 'worth': 0.02},
 {'id': 400900758444310528, 'worth': 0.04},
 {'id': 602213380274651400, 'worth': 0.06},
 {'id': 610603160301469715, 'worth': 0.17}]
```

To get the top 5 elements:

```
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: x['worth'], reverse=True)[:5]
[{'id': 610603160301469715, 'worth': 0.17},
 {'id': 602213380274651400, 'worth': 0.06},
 {'id': 400900758444310528, 'worth': 0.04},
 {'id': 651499863736844298, 'worth': 0.02},
 {'id': 242730576195354624, 'worth': 0.0}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `itemgetter`.

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(l,key=itemgetter('worth'))
```

---

```
[{'id': 242730576195354624, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 659311972990451712, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 365975655608745985, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 472141928578940958, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 270904126974590976, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 280497242714931202, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 432610292342587392, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 408785106942164992, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 622692428213780481, 'worth': 0.0},
 {'id': 651499863736844298, 'worth': 0.02},
 {'id': 400900758444310528, 'worth': 0.04},
 {'id': 602213380274651400, 'worth': 0.06},
 {'id': 610603160301469715, 'worth': 0.17}]
```

---

To get 5 largest values try this.

```
top_five=sorted(l,key=itemgetter('worth'))[-5:][::-1]

[{'id': 610603160301469715, 'worth': 0.17},
 {'id': 602213380274651400, 'worth': 0.06},
 {'id': 400900758444310528, 'worth': 0.04},
 {'id': 651499863736844298, 'worth': 0.02},
 {'id': 622692428213780481, 'worth': 0.0}]
```

---

If you want to sort in-place then use `.sort()` method with `key=itemgetter('worth')`

```
l.sort(key=itemgetter('worth')) # .sort() doen't return None. And it modifies the same list.
```

---

If you are sorting to only get the top 5 largest then. Using `heapq` doesn't require sorting.

```
from heapq import nlargest
top_five=nlargest(5,l,key=itemgetter('worth'))
```

---

```
[{'id': 610603160301469715, 'worth': 0.17},
 {'id': 602213380274651400, 'worth': 0.06},
 {'id': 400900758444310528, 'worth': 0.04},
 {'id': 651499863736844298, 'worth': 0.02},
 {'id': 242730576195354624, 'worth': 0.0}]
```

Comment: @ChristianSloper And `itemgetter` is faster than `lambda`.